# Как посчитать сумму int через лямбду?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Не понимаю принцип реализации подобных примеров, типа найти сумму чисел через лямбда выражения. Это не работает

```
Runnable sum1 = (a, b, c) -> { a + b + c };
sum1.run();
```

Comment: "Это не работает" - что это значит?

Comment: попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Непонятно, что вам нужно.

Comment: У ответов на Ваши вопросы слева есть значок "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Runnable` вам не подходит, так как `run` не принимает ни одного аргумента и ничего не возвращает:

```java
interface Runnable {
    void run();
}
```

По всей видимости, вам нужна лямбда, которая принимает 3 числа на вход и выдает число на выходе. Тогда создайте свой интерфейс `Sum`, например, так:

```java
interface Sum {
    int run(int a, int b, int c);
}
```

Далее, ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```java
Sum sum = (a, b, c) -> {
    return a + b + c;
};
System.out.println(sum.run(1, 2, 3));
```